# Can induced electric field produced by a body apply torque on itself?

Tags: electromagnetism, torque

I came across an interesting question that involved a hollow charged cylinder on which an external torque was applied. The question asked us to find the angular acceleration of the cylinder. In the solution, the torque produced by the induced electric field produced by the varying magnetic fields generated due to the rotation of the cylinder was taken into account to calculate the final angular acceleration. My question is whether this induced electric field can apply a torque on the body that is generating them as I thought that a body cannot apply torque on itself.
[image: This is the question I was talking about]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, induced electric field due to accelerating charge that is distributed not too singularly acts also on that same charge distribution, and the net force or torque need not be zero. This is the case for volume and surface distribution. (However, keep in mind this  self-interaction assumption breaks down for too singular distributions of charge, such as charge at a point or charge on a line).

This self-action of charge's own field on itself is the mechanism of *electromagnetic mass* or *self-inductance* in inductors. It is additional inertia towards changes of velocity (to the already existing mechanical one), due to presence of several interacting charges. In AC circuits, inductors are used due to having this effect pronounced - they are wound up so that mobile charge in them has much larger inertia due to self-action of the whole accelerated charge distribution in the coils, than due to mass of the electrons.

The spool example is similar to the inductor - the gravity force acts to create current (like electrostatic force of voltage source does in AC circuits), but self-action of the accelerated charge acts against that in the device, and this can be quantified by additional moment of inertia due to electromagnetic self-interaction.

EM inertia never stops the charge from accelerating, it just decreases the effect the external force has.